# define variable and run query in one query in php

Tags: php, mysql

this is my query it's work in MySQL, but I don't know how to do it in php.

`set @rank = 0;
update tbl a join (select id, @rank:=@rank+1 as rank from tbl order by id) b
  on a.id = b.id set a.id = b.rank;`

any idea? thank you

Comment: Search for `php mysqli tutorial` in google.

Comment: Post what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is two queries.

If you used mysql extension, you should run two queries on two different mysql_query();
like this:

```
mysql_query("set @rank = 0;");
mysql_query("update tbl a join (select id, @rank:=@rank+1 as rank from tbl order by id) b
on a.id = b.id set a.id = b.rank;");
```

It must work

Comment: Isn't mysql depracated??..... Use mysqli

Comment: Yes mysql extention is depracated. I think hama used mysql extension.